# reassignment python modules's variable, but function use that var as default don't change

Tags: python

there is example code:

```
# b.py
c = False
def d(i=c):
    print(i, c)
```

I want to write `a.py` to let the output of `b.d` to be `True, True`:

```
# a.py
import b
b.c = True
b.d()
```

but the output is `False, True`.

so, `why` and `how` to get it?

---

**write after answer**

to why:

```
# `inspect` may be useful
import inspect
v = True
def f(i=v):
    print(i, v)

s = inspect.signature(f)
s.parameters
Out[6]: mappingproxy({'i': <Parameter "i=True">})
```

Comment: You can't do what you want.  Your best bet is to write (ugh) `def d(i=None):` and then inside the function, `if i is None: i = c`.  This is for the same reason that using an empty list as a default argument can cause "unexpected" results.

Comment: my mistake! change now

Comment: You are changing the value of `c` in the module `b`, but the `d` function in module `b` has already been parsed and evaluated and its default for the argument `i` was already set to `False`. Python would be significantly slower if it had to always re-evaluate its function signatures.

Comment: I get it, so there is no easy way to change `STRICT = True` in [handle_error(strict=STRICT)](https://github.com/jaepil/pdfminer3k/blob/master/pdfminer/psparser.py#L7-L22) and let `handle_error` raise error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is unnecessarily complicated -- we can boil down your question to a few lines:

```
default = "Before"

def foo(bar=default):
    print(bar)

foo()              # "Before"
default = "After"
foo()              # "Before"
```

The behavior it seems you expect is that after `default = "After"`, calling `foo()` will print "After".  But it continues to print "Before".

Python will evaluate the default argument for a function *once* and "lock it in".  Reassigning the name of `default` to something else later has no effect (as we see in the snippet above).

Instead, you can use an approach that's commonly suggested when people want lists as default arguments:

```
default = "Before"

def foo(bar=None):
    if bar is None:
        bar = default
    print(bar)

foo()              # "Before"
default = "After"
foo()              # "After"
```

In this case, you're not trying to change the default argument, but rather change what is assigned to `bar` when no argument is specified.  Each time you call `foo()` with no argument, it'll be assigned `None` and then the logic inside the function will look up and use the value of the global `default`.

Answer (score 3):

That's because the default value is evaluated *once* at the creation of the function.

```
def d(i=c):
    print(i, c)
```

Here, after the `import b` line, the `d` function becomes

```
def d(i=False):
    print(i, c)
```

So changing `c` has no effect on the default value of `i` in `d`.